# Create 10k+ agents in clojure

Tags: concurrency, clojure, actor, agents

As I tested, a separate thread is used for each new agent, when I create them. 
Could several agents be run in one thread?

My idea is to create 10K+ light-weight agents (like actors in erlang), so is it a challenge for Clojure?

Thanks

Comment: What are these agents going to do?

Answer (score 9):

This is incorrect. Agents use a thread pool which is the number of core + 2 in size. So on a quad core machine even 10k+ agents will only use 6 worker threads.

With `send`, that is. With `send-off` new threads will be started.

Comment: Thank, but look for example next action function:
`(defn inc-state [a]
    (println a (Thread/currentThread))
    (Thread/sleep 5000)
    (println a 'Done')
    (merge a {:state (inc (a :state))})
)`
I want to make agent be able to send response after 5 secods, but with using Thread/sleep - it takes a thread and don't allow other agents to use threads. I need another way to send action after some time

Answer (score 3):

Consider using a j.u.c.DelayQueue

Here's a sketch of how it would work,

*the (`delayed-function` is a bit cumbersome here, but it basically constructs an instance of j.u.c.Delayed for submission to the queue.)*

```lisp
(import [java.util.concurrent Delayed DelayQueue TimeUnit])

(defn delayed-function [f]
  (let [execute-time    (+ 5000 (System/currentTimeMillis))
        remaining-delay (fn [t] (.convert t 
                                          (- execute-time 
                                              (System/currentTimeMillis))
                                          TimeUnit/MILLISECONDS))]
  (reify
      Delayed    (getDelay [_ t] (remaining-delay t))
      Runnable   (run [_] (f))
      Comparable (compareTo [_ _] 0))))

;;; Use java's DelayQueue from clojure.
;;; See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/DelayQueue.html

(def q (DelayQueue.))

(defn delayed 
  "put the function f on the queue, it will only execute after the delay 
   expires"
  [f]
  (.offer q (delayed-function f)))

(defn start-processing 
  "starts a thread that endlessly reads from the delay queue and 
   executes the function found in the queue"
  []
  (.start
   (Thread.
    #(while true
        (.run (.take q))))))

user> (start-processing)
user> (delayed #(println "Hello"))

   ; 5 seconds passes

Hello
```

Comment: Thanks,
assume we have an agent which is executing, and we have a delayed function which sends an action to executing agent. So will it be running in parallel or will wait till agent finishes execution of current function?

Answer (score 0):

the `at` function of [the at-at library](https://github.com/overtone/at-at/) that was developed to support the (in my opinion fantastic) Overtone music synthesizer provides a nice clean **interfase for running functions at a specific point in time**.

```
(use 'overtone.at-at)
(def my-pool (mk-pool))
(after 1000 #(println "hello from the past!") my-pool)
```